# Delphi - move control in runtime alike on design mode

Tags: delphi

Hy guys,

I try to move my own component on runtime mode with mouse alike in design mode.

the component isn't moved untill mouse button isn't released and in this time a empty frame is displayed and a hint show lefttop corner possition.

I done a lots of tries but no success untill now.

Any help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here (http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/?p=269) on my web, you can find a component called **TSelectOnRuntime**.  You can view the source code and study it. It's an simple approach to select, resize and move components on runtime.

[image]

[Download the demo](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/componentes/CSelectOnRunTime.zip) and evaluate, if it's valid for you (include the source of component, demo sources and compiled demos).

Comment: This components are free and the source is avaible (I'am the autor). 
This is the updated link in Github: https://github.com/NeftaliDelphi/GLib
This is the link to the license file: https://github.com/NeftaliDelphi/GLib/blob/main/leeme_en.txt

Comment: Note: The control is for Delphi 6 but works also on Delphi 11.2. The language is spanish. There are warnings (uninitialized vars). Otherwise, it works decent. +1 from me.

Answer (score 10):

Well, I'll post it here. The following code uses undocumented [WM_SYSCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) constant `$F012` and works with [TWinControl](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TWinControl) descendants.

Note, that it's undocumented and it might not work on future versions of Windows (as anything else from Windows API if they decide to), but it works (tested on several Windows versions) and it's the easiest way how to move the component at runtime.

```
procedure TForm.YourComponentMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
const
  SC_DRAGMOVE = $F012;
begin
  ReleaseCapture;
  YourComponent.Perform(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_DRAGMOVE, 0);
end;
```

The similar magic exists also for sizing, namely command `$F008`.

```
procedure TForm.YourComponentMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
const
  SC_DRAGSIZE = $F008;
begin
  ReleaseCapture;
  YourComponent.Perform(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_DRAGSIZE, 0);
end;
```

Comment: Note, that this method only works with TWinControl derivates !

Comment: Your magical `SC_DRAGSIZE` is in fact `SC_SIZE + WMSZ_BOTTOMRIGHT`. To size from the top-left for instance, you can use `SC_SIZE + WMSZ_TOPLEFT`.

Comment: @Sertac - much more magical than I thought :) But still I don't get why MS doesn't document it. IMHO this will keep alive to the future Windows versions because they surely use this in some product.

Comment: This is the same message used to move and resize top level windows. Deep inside windows these things are all just the same thing (a window, natch) and so it's not surprising that WM_SYSCOMMAND supports SC_DRAGMOVE both with top level window class (what a TForm really is) and any other Delphi control with a win32 window handle.

Answer (score 6):

If what i think you are trying to do is move controls at runtime, then here is some code you may use (and possibly modify slightly) to your needs:

```
var
MouseDownPos, LastPosition : TPoint;
DragEnabled,Resizing : Boolean;


procedure TForm1.ControlMouseDown(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
     MouseDownPos.X := X;
     MouseDownPos.Y := Y;
     DragEnabled := True;
end;

//handle dragging of controls
procedure TForm1.ControlMouseMove(Sender: TObject;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
     if DragEnabled then
     begin
          if Sender is TControl then
          begin
                TControl(Sender).Left := TControl(Sender).Left + (X - MouseDownPos.X);
                TControl(Sender).Top := TControl(Sender).Top + (Y - MouseDownPos.Y);
          end;
     end;
end;
```

For resizing controls you could use something like:

```
procedure TForm1.ControlMouseMove(Sender: TObject;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var cntrl : TControl;
begin
    cntrl := Sender as TControl;
if ((cntrl.Width - X) < 15) and ((cntrl.Height - Y) < 15) then
       cntrl.Cursor := crSizeNWSE
    else cntrl.Cursor := crDefault;
    if Resizing then
    begin
        cntrl.Width := cntrl.Width + (X - LastPosition.X);
        LastPosition.X := X;
        cntrl.Height := cntrl.Height + (Y - LastPosition.Y);
        LastPosition.Y := Y;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ControlMouseDown(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var cntrl : TControl;
begin
    if ((cntrl.Width - X) < 15) and ((cntrl.Height - Y) < 15) then
    begin
        LastPosition.X := X;
        LastPosition.Y := Y;
        Resizing := True;
    end;
end;
```

Extensions to this may be snapping to a grid. This code may need to be modified slightly.

Comment: ReleaseCapture; is best from my tests. But I lose mouse messages. for example will not get mouseup message.

Answer (score 4):

There is a component out there named `TSizeCtrl` which lets you move controls at runtime. You can find source code [here](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fidA96EEC1540E1F1AE4B289AD6F7E34D36864B8317.aspx?s=delphi) or the component for download at [Torry's](http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=822).

It can be used like this:

```
SizeCtrl1 := TSizeCtrl.Create(MyForm);
SizeCtrl1.GridSize := 20;
SizeCtrl1.Enabled := True;
SizeCtrl1.RegisterControl(MyControl);
SizeCtrl1.AddTarget(MyControl);
```

This will let you drag `MyControl` around and resize it. It draws a frame while dragging and provides the handles for resizing.

Comment: both links are broken

Comment: https://github.com/BakasuraRCE/TSizeCtrl Here's a good link for whoever needs it