# Delphi resize/crop frame around text box

Tags: delphi, textbox, edit, crop, wireframe

I am writing a program for printing labels (or modifying one i wrote a couple of years ago) - and i want the users to be able to design the layout of the labels (currently there are predefined label layouts which i have to edit if they want changes), having the ability to draw text boxs, lines etc on a canvas/form, then be able to select it to modify text, crop or resize. 
How can i draw the resize/crop frame similar to the resize/crop frames around text boxes/pics in word or the linux program gLables ?

I have put a TImage object on a form, and use that to draw the grid, lines, text etc.. is this the best way, or should i draw directly to the forms canvas, or something else ???

I am using delphi 2010.

Any pointers, suggestions, examples would be most helpful..
Thanks

---

Thanks guys for the replies, i also found an interesting article on about.com which might be of use to anyone else to is trying to do the same as me.

[link](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa102505a.htm)

Comment: The right way is to create a custom control for your designer.

Comment: Here's a link to a code sample of ["marching ants" over a TImage](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/Graphics/MarchingAntsOverTImage.ZIP).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi - move control in runtime alike on design mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952283/delphi-move-control-in-runtime-alike-on-design-mode)